# Is there any advantage to using SimpleHttpOperator over regular python requests in Airflow?

Tags: request, airflow

In airflow, I learned about using the Simple HttpOperator to grab json from an api. Without airflow I would just get the json using requests. Is there any advantage to using the airflow way rather than just hooking up a requests function to a PythonOperator?

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything with `PythonOperator`.
The variety of operators in Airflow are just to make your life easier - if operator fits to your use case fully it saves you the trouble of implementing it yourself. At the end all operators are implemented as Python function. The advantage is mostly with ease of use.

Comment: Gotcha, this makes a lot of sense thank you

Comment: If answered please accept